# Dynamically add JCombobox and JTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, jcombobox

I want to add a `JComboBox` and a `JTextField` to a panel when there is an item selected in the combobox.

I have this code for the panel.

```
aantallenGebruikt.add(new JTextField("", 5));
onderdelenGebruikt.add(new JComboBox(onderdelenBox()));
onderdelenGebruikt.get(0).addActionListener(MyFrame.this);

panelAfronden = new JPanel();
panelAfronden.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

panelAfronden.add(new JLabel("Selecteer onderdeelNr en Vul gebruikte aantallen in"));



panelAfronden2 = new JPanel();
panelAfronden2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

panelAfronden2.add(onderdelenGebruikt.get(0));
panelAfronden2.add(aantallenGebruikt.get(0));

JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(panelAfronden2);
sPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220, 230));

panelAfronden.add(sPane);

panelAfronden.add(new JLabel("Opmerkingen"));
opmerkingenAfronden = new JTextArea(5, 20);
panelAfronden.add(opmerkingenAfronden);

rondAf = new JButton("Rond Werkzaamheid Af");
rondAf.addActionListener(MyFrame.this);
panelAfronden.add(rondAf);

annuleer = new JButton("Annuleer");
annuleer.addActionListener(MyFrame.this);
panelAfronden.add(annuleer);
```

I have this in the ActionListener

```
    if( eventSource == onderdelenGebruikt){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
```

I know how to add the combobox and textfield to the panel but At the moment it doesn't even print out the `test` to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question:

> I know how to add the combobox and textfield to the panel but At the moment it doesn't even print out the test to the console.

Answer:

> Store the reference of `JcomboBox` some where and then check the source in `ActionListener`.

do in this way:

```
    final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(onderdelenBox());
    onderdelenGebruikt.add(comboBox);

    comboBox.addActionListener(MyFrame.this);
```

Your `ActionListener` will look like this.

```
if( eventSource == comboBox ){
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

Comment: I just did that, but how do I Listen for events for the other comboboxes in the `onderdelenGebruikt` that I will add Dynamically?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have look, You can define a single `ActionListener` that is used for multiple `JComboBox` at a time. Just check the instance of source in `ActionListener`

Comment: So if I do something like this `onderdeelNr = new JComboBox(onderdelenBox());
   onderdelenGebruikt.add(onderdeelNr);
   JTextField onderdeelAantal = new JTextField("",5);
   aantallenGebruikt.add(onderdeelAantal);
   
   panelAfronden2.add(onderdeelNr);
   panelAfronden2.add(onderdeelAantal);` it should work?

Comment: Sorry It will not work. you can't add same component two times in different panels. You have create separate instance for each `JComboBox` as well as `JTextArea`.

Comment: I added `onderdeelNr.addActionListener(this);` to the code above after `onderdeelNr = new JComboBox(onderdelenBox());` and it works like a charm

Comment: So the problem was with the check `eventSource == onderdelenGebruikt` where you are checking for `JPanel` rather then `JComboBox`. You got it.

Comment: Correction: It does add it, but the comboboxes are useless as I can't get the right information from them. how do I create a new instance everytime the last combobox added is used?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. What information you want to get?

Comment: You can call `comboBox.getParent()` to get its parent and that is `onderdelenGebruikt` in your case.

Comment: I want to get all the indexes of the selected items in the comboboxes, and how do I add an ActionListener to the Panel?

Comment: What you want to add an `ActionListener` on `JPanel`. Use `comboBox.getSelectedIndex()` to get the selected index.

Comment: Your original question is `I know how to add the combobox and textfield to the panel but At the moment it doesn't even print out the test to the console`. I think that is resolved.